# Announcing a “Graduation” election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Computational Science Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [an election](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **November 1**, as your “graduation” election as a result of [having lost your beta label a while back](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/14963).

The timeline:

- On October 25, I'll post a question collection post on Meta, so that the community can post questions they'd like to see the candidates answer.
- Starting on November 1, users can [nominate themselves](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/election/2). The top questions collected on the previous week will be compiled into a questionnaire on the election page, so that potential moderators can answer them.
- The existing moderator team will need to run in the election if they wish to keep their positions.
- On November 8, if there are 4 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period there are still less than 4 candidates, we'll cancel the election. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on November 16 (or November 23, if we need to extend the nomination period).

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.